# Click Once Deployment - Additional non-compile time dependecies

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I have a winforms application that I want to deploy via clickonce.  What is a little different about this application is that it searches for certain assemblies (by name convention) in the working directory and loads/reflects over them to find ninject modules/providers. The assemblies it loads are not referenced by the VS project. It works a treat, but how do I include these assemblies in the clickonce deployment package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dll's to your project as files instead of references, and set the type of the `Build Action` to `Content` and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer` (Copy to output does not effect Click-Once but it does affect local builds)

[image]

Once you have set the build action to content the dll's should be included with the deployment, you can check under `Project Properties -> Publish -> Application Files...`

[image]